# Licensing concerns for website created with Visual Studio Express

Tags: licensing, visual-studio-express

If I make a website using Microsoft Visual Studio Express, do I have to take any license or something in any sense?

I'm deploying to a server which has Microsoft SQL Server Express.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a license for Windows Server, but that is all.  There is nothing else needed beyond that for IIS, ASP.Net, MVC, or Sql Server Express Edition.

Or, put another way, Microsoft gives you a license for all of those things that you can use in a commercial production environment.